# Something wrong with Coding Style

Tags: java, coding-style

Is there something wrong with my coding style here? 
This is for homework and I was trying to submit it but it says my style is wrong :/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Groucho {
    String secret;
    public Groucho(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }
    public boolean saysSecret(String line) {
        if (line.indexOf(secret) != -1)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your secret word here: ");
        String a = in.nextLine();
        Groucho x = new Groucho(a);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence until you win the game");
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String inp = in.nextLine();
            if (x.saysSecret(inp)) {
                System.out.println("You have won $100 for saying " + a);
                break;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my style checker says is wrong:

```
Request 1
File received, running checkstyle...
Starting audit...
Groucho.java:20: while child at indentation level 11 not at correct indentation, 12
Groucho.java:21: if at indentation level 11 not at correct indentation, 12
Groucho.java:22: if child at indentation level 15 not at correct indentation, 16
Groucho.java:22: method call child at indentation level 15 not at correct indentation, 16
Groucho.java:23: if child at indentation level 15 not at correct indentation, 16
Groucho.java:24: if rcurly at indentation level 11 not at correct indentation, 12
Groucho.java:25: else at indentation level 11 not at correct indentation, 12
Groucho.java:26: method call child at indentation level 15 not at correct indentation, 16
Audit done.

Done!
```

Comment: One nitpick: change `saysSecret()` to simply be `return line.indexOf(secret) >= 0;`.

Comment: This question is better fitted for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: whats the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I just needed to add a space between each method. Stupid but yeah.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I like to do is put line breaks to group relevant code into chunks or paragraphs. I think it makes the code easier to read. As for your error messages, it looks like you need to indent your lines one more space? It appears they are one level less than what is expected.

Comment: got it....      nnnnnnnn

Comment: It's always the little things. Your style is looking good by the way, keep it up!

Comment: I got a question... When I'm making a class and I'm making a constructor method... i have to first initialize the variables outside the constructor method right? like i did there? String secret;

Comment: That is the best practice. Initialize the variable outside of the constructor then give the variable a value inside the constructor. You have it perfect.